# Abstract Factory Improvements

Tags: c++

Edited: I decided to edit this post for future readers. Put simply, it shows an acceptable way to call constructors of template types within the template list. For example, the following:

```
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<factory> real_widget_factory(new widget_factory(5.0, 6.0));
}
```

Instead of just being limited to:

```
    unique_ptr<factory> real_widget_factory(new widget_factory()); // empty
```

Comment: There is a LOT of code in this question, and I'm not sure any of it is helpful. What is it you actually are trying to do? What is the code that you're trying to achieve supposed to do?

Comment: At the very end, where it says "so that I can achieve this"... I want to be able to pass in arguments into the constructor of real_train_factory, instead of just leaving it up a particular default ctor. The important code is in the header, which is first.

Comment: @rightfold or maybe http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I'm aware that I can just use boost libraries to achieve this: http://arcticinteractive.com/static/boost/libs/factory/doc/html/factory/abstract_factory.html#factory.abstract_factory.tutorial.smartptrs
The point is, I want to write it myself.... I guess an alternative way to see this is that I didn't just use boost's abstract factory to begin with.

Comment: @Gustav: That is not what he meant. What he meant is that the whole concept of the abstract factory is completely pointless. It's just a function object and `boost::function`/`std::function` already implements that whole thing.

Comment: @Puppy. Humor me and just take a look? I think the last paragraph should clarify what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Gustav: It does not clarify how what you want cannot be trivially implemented on top of std::function.

Comment: @Puppy because the abstract_factory struct in my code was not designed to compile with that feature... It needs to be amended, and I don't know how to do it .

Comment: @Gustav: Have a look at the answer I posted. It's far simpler than your code and way more flexible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75642/discussion-between-gustav-and-puppy).

Answer (score 1):

The Standard provides all the necessary infrastructure you need. You can delete all of that code.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
struct train_factory {
    train_factory(std::function<std::unique_ptr<locomotive>()> ml,
        std::function<std::unique_ptr<freight_car>()> mc)
        : make_locomotive(std::move(ml)),
        , make_car(std::move(mc)) {}
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<locomotive>()> make_locomotive;
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<freight_car>()> make_car;
};
train_factory make_concrete_factory(double x1, double x2) {
    return train_factory(
        [=] { return make_unique<real_locomotive>(x1); },
        [=] { return make_unique<real_car>(x2); }
    );
}
int main() {        
    auto fact = make_concrete_factory(1.0);
    auto loc = fact.make_locomotive();
}
```

This appears to meet all of your requirements. In this case, the functions have the arguments to the factory bound in (and this binding is arbitrary). You can of course also modify the functions to take the arguments if you like, or use both in arbitrary ways and combinations.

```
struct train_factory {
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<locomotive>(double)> make_locomotive;
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<freight_car>(double)> make_car;
};
train_factory make_concrete_factory() {
    return train_factory {
        [](double x1) { return make_unique<real_locomotive>(x1); },
        [](double x2) { return make_unique<real_car>(x2); }
    };
}
int main() {        
    auto fact = make_concrete_factory();
    auto loc = fact.make_locomotive(1.0);
}
```

Comment: I get the same errors i've been getting.
"Candidate ctor (the implicit move ctor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided.
Candidate ctor (the implicit copy ctor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided.
Candidate ctor (the implicit default ctor) not viable: requires 0 argument, but 2 were provided."

Comment: @Gustav: What is the exact code that you have a problem with? Oh, I used uniform initialization which your compiler may not support yet, so you may need to add a constructor to train_factory and call it directly instead of using uniform init.

Comment: The concrete_factory and abstract_factory structs in the header file at the top of these post.

Comment: Delete them- you don't need them anymore. `train_factory` is the new `abstract_factory` and `concrete_factory` is no longer required.

Comment: Wait, standby. I think I have it. OK, but what IF I want to keep those. How would I approach it? For educational purposes...

Comment: within your lambdas I am getting 2 parse issues, "expected expression" and "expected '(' for functional style cast or type construction.

Comment: @Gustav: YOu probably didn't provide `make_unique`, which is pretty trivial. I'll add it to the question. Either that or your compiler doesn't support uniform init (as above). I changed my first sample to be a bit easier to digest.